# Extract ip, mask and gateway of a network interface separately

Tags: interface, command

I know that the command `ifconfig` will give you ip, mask and gateway of a given network interface. I want to "programmatically" extract each of those paramaters separately. At the moment the best solution I can think of is to do some parsing by using `grep`.

Are there `ifconfig` flags to single out ip, mask or gateway? Are there other *nix commands that will extract just one parameter of a given network interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theses are not very elaborates but seems to work at least:

for bond0:

Get the IP

> ifconfig | awk '/bond0/ { getline; print}' | awk '{print $2}' | awk
>   'BEGIN {FS=":"} ; {print $2}'

Get the the broadcast address:

> ifconfig | awk '/bond0/ { getline; print}' | awk '{print $3}' | awk
>   'BEGIN {FS=":"} ; {print $2}'

Get the netmask:

> ifconfig | awk '/bond0/ { getline; print}' | awk '{print $4}' | awk
>   'BEGIN {FS=":"} ; {print $2}'

and for the Gateway:

> route  | awk '/default/ {  print $2}'

sure someone will get there with something more simple or straighforward.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Not pretty, but gets the job done, I guess.